# Display an error message if the user dosenot exist on the same login form

Tags: php, authentication

Here is a problem i am having.
I have a loginform.php and when the user clicks the login button I want to display an error message on the same 'loginform.php' on my '#diverror' div if the user dose not exist.

loginform.php

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<div style='width:500px;margin:auto;border:2px solid darkgrey;margin-top: 50px;'>
    <table id='logintable'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style='text-align: center;font-weight: bold;'>Login</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button type= submit>Login</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="diverror">     </div>
</div>
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

        $sqlcommand = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($sqlcommand,$db);

        include 'loginform.php'; 
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>=1)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            $dbpass = $row['password'];
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbactive = $row['active'];
            $_SESSION['username']=$dbuser;
            header ('Location: index.php');

        }
        else // If the user dose not exist,
        {
            //Display this message on the loginform.php > #diverror
        }


?>
```

Comment: **A:** Use [**Ajax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) for that. --- Sidenote: Stop using `MySQL_` - either use `MySQLi_` or better yet, PDO.

Comment: Heyy fred !! , `session_start()` is missing on your code.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Hey Shankar... um, which code? lol never mind, I got it. lol

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Maybe the OP has `session_start();` inside `connect.php` ;-)

Comment: Yeah right mate. Possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Store error message in `SESSION`...

```
else // If the user dose not exist,
{
    $_SESSION['msg']="User does not exist";
    header("Location: loginform.php");
    exit();
}
```

then just echo SESSION variable, after displaying message you need to `unset` session variable.

```
<div id="diverror">
   <?php echo $_SESSION['msg'];
   unset($_SESSION['msg']); ?>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** must start session at the beginning of the both files..

```
session_start();
```

Comment: `session_start();` may very well be inside OP's `connect.php` file. It usually ends up being the case. ;-) (which isn't the actual issue here).

Comment: $_SESSION is bad for Google ?

Comment: @jacouh how can you say that?

Comment: This is the case if $_SESSION vars are appended to URL arguments. If not I don't see inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works. But the problem is that it keeps showing up the error message whenever I open up the loginform.php even though the user hasn't pressed the login button.

Comment: you need to unset the session

Comment: where do I unset the session ?

Comment: @Eskinder check my updated answer, you need to unset the session

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this showing up even when a user has not logged in yet, use
    `<div class="text-error ">`
    `<?php` 
    `session_start();`
    `if (isset($_SESSION['msg']))`
    `{`
    `echo $_SESSION['msg'];`
    `}`
    `unset($_SESSION['msg']); ?>`
    `</div>`
This way, error will only show up if msg has been set and this can only happen when user submits.